# italic small caps in Garamond #3?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, italic, small-caps

I have the OTF files for Garamond #3 LT Pro, supplied by my publisher.  I need to use italic small caps.  The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond3LTPro}[
  Extension = .otf ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ]

\fontspec{Garamond3LTPro-Italic.otf}[Letters=SmallCaps]

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Letters=SmallCaps' (+smcp) not available for font
* 'Garamond3LTPro-Italic.otf' with script 'Latin' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
```

The publisher insists that Garamond #3 LT Pro Italic has a small caps.  Is he wrong, and if so how can I prove it?

What makes me suspicious is that this page:

> http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/garamond-3/pro-roman/specs.html

lists smcp among the tags, but this page:

> http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/garamond-3/pro-italic/specs.html

does not.

The need for italic small caps is the following.  French typography is fond of small caps, in particular for centuries for which roman numerals are used: {\scshape xviii}e siècle (not 18e siècle).  In a bibliography, book titles are in italics, and, as we say in English, voilà.  (Author names in bibliographies are also in sc, but upright, which Garamond 3 has).

Since my need is limited to a few century numbers in the bibliography (set in 9pt), I suppose that a fake it-sc would be good enough.

Comment: By the way, 
[welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Incidentally, the Roman (i.e., upright) font face of Garamond #3 does feature small-caps glyphs. It's just italic font face that's missing them.

Comment: Or (ideally) convince your publisher not to use italic small caps. To what nefarious purpose will they be put?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: I guess you just have created a second account by accident. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already know from myfonts.com, *Garamond 3* has **no** small caps italics. I guess that your editor has been using «fake» small caps, which *InDesign*, *LibreOffice* or *Word* can produce. I strongly advise not to use them. Instead, you should try some «real» small caps from other Garamond versions. There are quite a few.

For instance, EB Garamond:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\emph{\textsc{\lipsum[1]}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Italic small caps in roman numerals for centuries in French. NB. I added some space between the small caps and the superscript e, because it would look otherwise somewhat cramped.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\newcommand{\siecle}[1]{\emph{
    \textsc{#1}\kern.1em\textsuperscript{e}
    {siècle}}}
\begin{document}
    \siecle{xv}
    \siecle{xvi}
    \siecle{xvii}
    \siecle{xviii}
    \siecle{xix}
    \siecle{xx}
    \siecle{xxi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for a good answer. As an aside, this doesn't look like a very good font, in my opinion.  Look at the kerning between I and N in `INTEGER` or between R and A… – it just looks a little half-finished.  I wouldn't use it in a production document.

Comment: @SeanAllred -- Good eye. It looks like the kerning between many capital letters and a following 'small' letter is too big ('Na'; 'Mo'; 'Ma'; etc.). Actually, I wonder if the small 'o' is just plain bad.  However, given the (now) stated need for italic, small caps for roman numerals, it may be a decent (enough) solution. Ludenticus, given the OP's addendum, your answer may be improved if you add roman numerals from 1-21 to the provided image.

Comment: @SeanAllred EB Garamond is indeed a work in progress, and judgments about its quality should be provisional.  But the poor kerning seen in the image seems to have more to do with the package `ebgaramond` than with the font, because when I use `fontspec` and `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}` and compile with `luatex` or `xetex`, the kerning is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Three high-quality commercial garaldes that feature small-cap italics are `Sabon Next` (by Tschichold and Porchez), `Palatino nova` (by Zapf and Kobayashi), and `Garamond Premier Pro` (by Slimbach (?)). Among these three fonts, GPP clearly is the most condensed, while Palatino is the least condensed. The Palatino *italic* shape is also the least slanted of the three.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\setmainfont{Sabon Next LT Pro}
\subsubsection*{Sabon Next LT Pro}
Le \textsc{xviii}\textsuperscript{e} siècle, 
\textit{le \textsc{xviii}\kern0.5pt\textsuperscript{e} siècle}


\setmainfont{Palatino nova}
\subsubsection*{Palatino nova}
Le \textsc{xviii}\textsuperscript{e} siècle, 
\textit{le \textsc{xviii}\kern0.5pt\textsuperscript{e} siècle}

\setmainfont[ItalicFont = Garamond Premier Pro Italic]{Garamond Premier Pro}
\subsubsection*{Garamond Premier Pro}
Le \textsc{xviii}\textsuperscript{e} siècle, 
\textit{le \textsc{xviii}\kern0.75pt\textsuperscript{e} siècle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that they would benefit from some kerning between the roman numerals and the superscript e (just as EB Garamond). Sabon Next is a redesign of Jean François Porchez from the monotype of Tschichold.

Comment: @Ludenticus - Many thanks for these comments and suggestions. I've added a `0.5pt` kern in the italic versions of Sabon and Palatino, and `0.75pt` kern in the italic version of GPP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the GPP suggestion! You saved my day!!